# Can we use Present perfect tense to talk about past?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

In a given [linked video](https://youtu.be/AuCJGtSTS_c?t=69) (around 1:09) Mom is explaining past to her daughter. But While explaining her she used Present perfect tense in between, why? Is to correct to use?

> Girl: Mom, so why are we white?
>
> Mom: Well, one day, God was passing through a park, and he noticed the beautiful little black girl sitting alone playing with the white clay. She was trying to make a doll for her to play with. He stopped there to watch her closely. Her beautiful little hands were full of white clay. **She has almost painted** herself with the white clay, and he was amused to see her. So he decided to make more people and paint them white.

Comment: For context, I included a longer transcription. I tried my best to transcribe the words and include proper punctuation, but I wasn't able to understand a few of the articles. From what I can tell, they don't appear to be "native" speakers.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's anomalous.

I agree with the transcription, but I don't think a native speaker would say this, except by mistake.

It's possible to tell a story in the "narrative present" - *God is passing ... She is trying to make ... Her ... hands are full ... She has almost painted ...*; but it's distinctly odd to slip into the present for just one sentence.

It's either a slip of the tongue, or her non-native command of English. I suspect the first.